# OGR_STYLE BRUSH not applied

Tags: kml, style, ogr2ogr, libkml

I have a shapefile that contains multiple polygons. I want to convert it to a kml but also keep the face color. From other answers here, I have found that I can add a field called OGR_STYLE to the shapefile and specify the fill parameters as a string:

```
OGR_STYLE: BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)
```

I then use ogr2ogr to convert the shapefile to a kml using the kml and libkml drivers:

```
ogr2ogr -f kml -f libkml output.kml input.shp
```

This appears to run okay, however my kml does not have a blue face color as expected. The outline is black, as expected, but there is no face color.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The name of the format is "kml" and two drivers can create it. If both drivers are available GDAL picks up the first one that it finds. Drivers can be skipped with configuration option `--config GDAL_SKIP KML`. For getting more debug into you can also use `--debug on`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to specify two output drivers, KML and LIBKML. Don't. Just specify LIBKML.

Make sure your OGR_STYLE field has the literal text:

```
BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)
```

*Not*

```
OGR_STYLE: BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)
```

So your command would look like:

```
ogr2ogr -f libkml output.kml input.shp
```

Which results in the below for my test data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="root_doc">
    <Schema id="test.schema">
      <SimpleField name="id" type="float"/>
      <SimpleField name="OGR_STYLE" type="string"/>
    </Schema>
    <Document id="test">
      <name>test</name>
      <Placemark id="test.1">
        <Style>
          <LineStyle>
            <color>ff000000</color>
            <width>1</width>
          </LineStyle>
          <PolyStyle>
            <color>ffff0000</color>
          </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#test.schema">
            <SimpleData name="id">1</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="OGR_STYLE">BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                142.285185185185,-10.8555555555555,0
                142.428395061728,-10.6641975308642,0
                142.703703703704,-10.7185185185185,0
                142.733333333333,-10.8518518518518,0
                142.418518518519,-10.920987654321,0
                142.285185185185,-10.8555555555555,0
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
    </Document>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

[image]

Comment: In an answer I now cannot find, it said I should specify both drivers. When I use the libkml driver alone, I get "Invalid Polygon" errors and the file is not written. I have the libkml driver installed, but it doesn't convert the file

Comment: Then you've got something else going on with your data, like the error says you have an invalid polygon.  Some formats are more tolerant of invalid geometries than others.  You can try setting `LIBKML_STRICT_COMPLIANCE FALSE`, i.e.  `ogr2ogr --config LIBKML_STRICT_COMPLIANCE FALSE -f libkml out.kml in.shp`. You can't write an output using multiple drivers, gdal simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yeah something funky is goin on for sure. It creates the kml ok (no invalid polygons) with the kml driver but not with libkml. I'll look under the hood...

Comment: Hopefully you've figured out your idiosyncratic problem by now, but if not: have you tried a 2 step answer, first writing out with the kml driver to an intermediate file (with no invalid polygons but no BRUSH) and then converting that intermediate file to kml with the libkml driver so it picks up the BRUSH?